# Get selected file from Desktop C#

Tags: c#, windows, shell

I would like to get the files path of the files selected from the user on the desktop, with this code I can get all file from the explorer

```
public void GetListOfSelectedFilesAndFolderOfWindowsExplorer()
{
    Shell exShell = new Shell();
    List<string> selected = new List<string>();
    foreach (ShellBrowserWindow window in (IShellWindows)exShell.Windows())
    {
        // check both for either interface to work
        // add an Exit for to just work the first explorer window 
        if ((window.Document as IShellFolderViewDual) != null)
        {
            foreach (FolderItem fi in window.Document.SelectedItems)
                selected.Add(fi.Path);
        }
        else if ((window.Document as ShellFolderView) != null)
        {
            foreach (FolderItem fi in window.Document.SelectedItems)
                selected.Add(fi.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the files names of the files in the desktop, but the list result empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "i got file right click in file explorer"? That's very unclear.

Comment: This is probably the wrong test: `filename.ToLowerInvariant() == "explorer"`  Where did it come from?

Comment: It looks like collection returned by `exShell.Windows()` does not contain Desktop. You could open another explorer windows and select files in there and they would be there in your list

Answer (score 0):

the files paths selected is not clear for me, but try the below code to get the list of files and folders in the user desktop

```
// Get the path of the user's desktop
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

// Get the paths of all files and directories on the desktop
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(desktopPath);
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(desktopPath);

// Create a string to store the paths
string message = "";

// Add all files to the message
foreach (string file in files)
{
    message += file + "\n";
}

// Add all directories to the message
foreach (string directory in directories)
{
    message += directory + "\n";
}

// Show the message in a message box
MessageBox.Show(message, "Paths of files and directories on desktop", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

To get list of selected folders or files, first you have to select the folders or files you need, and this must be done using a tool like FolderBrowserDialog and OpenFileDialog.

Here is an example of how you might use the OpenFileDialog to allow the user to select multiple files on the desktop:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Get the paths of the selected files
    string[] selectedFiles = openFileDialog1.FileNames;

    // Add all files to the list box
    foreach (string file in selectedFiles)
    {
        message += file + "\n";
    }
}
```

And for selecting folders you can use FolderBrowserDialog

```
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Get the path of the selected directory
    string directory = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    message =  directory;
}
```

Comment: no OP does not want list of `all` files. they want list of files `selected` by user. meaning if you want to copy some files, you would first `select` them and then drag them to another folder to copy. So OP wants the list of files on the desktop which are in `selected` state,

Comment: To get list of selected folders or files, first you have to select the folders or files you need, and this must be done using a tool like FolderBrowserDialog and OpenFileDialog.
The answer edited to show that